# ember-data needs full object for saving data not only the id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i currently have the problem, that ember-data needs a full object to get saved.
Before i can save i need to ask the store for all the full objects.
here is a example of what i need to do.

I added my code to store data and the models. Is this the correct way of doing this? Working with promises produces always a lot of code and makes everything hard to read.

Any indeas?

Kind Regards
Markus

```
this.store.find('fighter', parseInt(this.newRecord.fighter,10)).then(function(data) {
    newRegistration.Fighter = data;
    controller.store.find('fightRule', parseInt(controller.newRecord.fightRule,10)).then(function(data) {
        newRegistration.FightRule = data;
        controller.store.find('weightClass', parseInt(controller.newRecord.weightClass,10)).then(function(data) {
            newRegistration.WeightClass = data;
            controller.store.find('fightClass', parseInt(controller.newRecord.fightClass,10)).then(function(data) {
                newRegistration.FightClass = data;
                var myNewRecord = controller.store.createRecord('registeredFighter', newRegistration);
                controller.model.event.get('RegisteredFighter').addObject(myNewRecord);
                myNewRecord.save();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

------------------------- MODELS --------------------------------

```
App.Fighter = DS.Model.extend({
  Name:  DS.attr('string'),
  Club:  DS.belongsTo('club', { async: true }),
  Birthday:  DS.attr('date'),
  MembershipNr:  DS.attr('number')
});

App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
  Name:  DS.attr('string'),
  Thumbnail:  DS.attr('string'),
  Ort:  DS.attr('string'),
  Contact:  DS.attr('string'),
  RegisteredFighter: DS.hasMany('registeredFighter', { async: true })
});

App.Club = DS.Model.extend({
  Name:  DS.attr('string'),
  Contact:  DS.attr('string'),
});

App.FightRule = DS.Model.extend({
  Name:  DS.attr('string')
});

App.WeightClass = DS.Model.extend({
  Name:  DS.attr('string')
});

App.FightClass = DS.Model.extend({
  Name:  DS.attr('string'),
  TabName: function() {
    return 'tab' + this.get('Name').underscore().capitalize();
  }.property('Name')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  Name:  DS.attr('string'),
  AllowFighter:  DS.attr('boolean'),
  AllowEvents: DS.attr('boolean'),
  IsAdmin: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.RegisteredFighter = DS.Model.extend({
  Fighter:  DS.belongsTo('fighter', { async: true }),
  FightRule:  DS.belongsTo('fightRule', { async: true }),
  WeightClass: DS.belongsTo('weightClass', { async: true }),
  FightClass: DS.belongsTo('fightClass', { async: true })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should read [You're missing the point of promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Promises can chain, if you return a promise from `.then`. So, your code can be rewritten like this:

```
this.store.find('fighter', parseInt(this.newRecord.fighter,10)).then(function(data) {
    newRegistration.Fighter = data;
    return controller.store.find('fightRule', parseInt(controller.newRecord.fightRule,10));

}).then(function(data) {
    newRegistration.FightRule = data;
    return controller.store.find('weightClass', parseInt(controller.newRecord.weightClass,10));

}).then(function(data) {
    newRegistration.WeightClass = data;
    return controller.store.find('fightClass', parseInt(controller.newRecord.fightClass,10));

}).then(function(data) {
    newRegistration.FightClass = data;
    var myNewRecord = controller.store.createRecord('registeredFighter', newRegistration);
    controller.model.event.get('RegisteredFighter').addObject(myNewRecord);

    return myNewRecord.save();

}).catch(function(reason) {
    // handle errors
});
```

Second, it looks like the later async calls don't use data from the earlier ones; you're just building up the data needed to create a new `registeredFighter`. So you can make all these requests in a single line of code with `Ember.RSVP.hash`:

```
var promises = {
    Fighter: this.store.find('fighter', parseInt(this.newRecord.fighter, 10)),
    FightRule: this.store.find('fightRule', parseInt(this.newRecord.fightRule, 10)),
    WeightClass: this.store.find('weightClass', parseInt(this.newRecord.weightClass, 10)),
    FightClass: this.store.find('fightClass', parseInt(this.newRecord.fightClass, 10)),
};

Ember.RSVP.hash(promises).then(function(data) {
    newRegistration.setProperties(data);
    var myNewRecord = controller.store.createRecord('registeredFighter', newRegistration);
    controller.model.event.get('RegisteredFighter').addObject(myNewRecord);

    return myNewRecord.save();
}).catch(function(reason) {
    // handle errors
});
```

So, that's how you can clean up your async code. But it still looks like you have a design problem here. The reason this is hard is because it's not the typical way of doing things :) Without more info about it it's hard to help. Just know you can set the `id` of an associated model on a new model, to create it. You don't need all the data (the stuff coming back from `store.find`) just to persist a new record and its relationships.

Comment: How can i set only the id? Just setting it? I got a error message if i did not use the full object.